# Terraform Azure AKS - Terraform Plan failing due to "connection refused" errors

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform

I am working with in an Azure Environment that was 100% deployed using Terraform (All Networking, Servers, Firewall, Everything). This environment was abandoned for some time but the IAC code was been constantly upgraded against other Environments. Recently I had to run the initial terraform plan that completed successfully. The apply took a long time and it was deleting a lot of objects. Somewhere down the process apply failed. Since then been having issues with subsequent "terraform plan". Most of the errors were related to AKS so decided to cleanup everything related to AKS.

I started by disabled any terraform job that would create AKS objects. Now I am to the poing where stuck with a bunch of Error messages:

```
null_resource.storage_account_enc_keys["event_hub"]: Refreshing state... [id=7769823871044950433]
null_resource.storage_account_enc_keys["network"]: Refreshing state... [id=4738858682472456831]
null_resource.storage_account_enc_keys["ssrs"]: Refreshing state... [id=7895464809071918822]
null_resource.storage_account_enc_keys["cdn"]: Refreshing state... [id=6960405350375997435]
null_resource.storage_account_enc_keys["webjob"]: Refreshing state... [id=1824168849553984961]
null_resource.storage_account_enc_keys["app"]: Refreshing state... [id=4341458091367408638]
null_resource.storage_account_enc_keys["media_services"]: Refreshing state... [id=7860082878767368564]
Error: Get "http://localhost/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles/k8s-cluster-reader": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable
Error: Get "http://localhost/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles/cluster-writers": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
Error: Get "http://localhost/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterrolebindings/cluster-admins-binding": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/pod-identity/limitranges/pod-identity": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/nginx-ingress/limitranges/nginx-ingress": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
Error: Get "http://localhost/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterrolebindings/k8s-cluster-writer-binding": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/linkerd/limitranges/linkerd": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused

Terraform Plan Exit Code: 1
```

Any idea how i can get past this without having to rebuild the environment completely???

Note: Most reference found only regarding this error points to adding load_config_file = false to the kubernetes provider. This was already in there. Plus my goal is using the next apply to remove anything related to AKS.

Comment: Are all those localhost APIs configured in your local environment?

Comment: Hi,, No I think they are all part of the Terraform Azure AKS provider. To be honest I am not 100% where those localhost/api coming from. I tried to commenting out everything related to AKS and namespace but still getting those errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue, when the kubernetes provider is configured based on attributes returned by the cluster resource. Certain changes to the cluster resource, cause the attributes the provider is configured with to be in known-after-apply state. In that case, the provider will not have a configuration and return that localhost connection error.

The solution is, to first manually apply the changes to the cluster resource using `terraform apply --target ...`. Then, after that you can run apply again, without the `--target` parameter.